# Create a new char to pass to method in C

Tags: c++, c, arduino

I have the following piece of code from the RadioHead library. Essentially I want to pass the following variables as 1 char array to a method. Variable: From, data and "newData:"

The code:

```
 if (manager.recvfromAckTimeout(buf, &len, 1000, &from))
    {
      Serial.print("got reply from : 0x");
      Serial.print(from, HEX);
      Serial.print(": ");
      Serial.println((char*)buf);
      
      client.send("newData:" + from + ";" +(char*)buf);
    }
```

The error is in the last line of code. This is a method to send data to a websocket. I get the following error:

```
exit status 1
invalid operands of types 'const char*' and 'const char [2]' to binary 'operator+'
```

How can I fix this? It is a horror working with string and char in C. My Arduino freezes when I use strings for some reason. I am trying to find a way by using only chars

Basically what I want is something like this

```
char newData[] = "newData:" + from + (char*)buf;
```

Comment: What is the exact type of `buf` ?

Comment: Looks like uint8. This is the source code of the library I am using, it is only the first part of the method. - bool RHRouter::recvfromAck(uint8_t* buf, uint8_t* len, uint8_t* source, uint8_t* dest, uint8_t* id, uint8_t* flags, uint8_t* hops)

Comment: Are you interested in C++ solutions or did you just use that tag to get a bit more attention?

Comment: So the buffer is a counted one, not necessarily a NUL-terminated one: how would C++ know how to properly construct a string from it? Why not create your own local `char` buffer, format your message into it, then pass that NUL-terminated buffer to `client.send()` ?

Comment: Arduino actually normally uses C++, not C, but encourages very careful memory management.

Comment: It looks like `from` is a number, in which case `"newData:" + from` is not what you want either.

Comment: C don't can not concatenate strings using `+` operator. Use [strcat](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat/) instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can't "add" string literals and `char*` instances together with the `+` operator in C to get a coherent string.  Nor in C++, unless `std::string` is in the mix.

So instead of this:

```
client.send("newData:" + from + ";" +(char*)buf);
```

This:

```
std::ostringstream ss;
ss << "newData:";
ss << from;
ss << ";";
std::string msg = ss.str() + std::string((char*)buf,len);
client.send(msg.c_str());
```

I'm assuming `buf` is binary data that may have null chars inside it, not just ascii chars. Hence an explicit concatenation with `len` to the string `s`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunately this error appears when attempting this solution: no match for 'operator+' (operand types are 'std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}' and 'uint8_t {aka unsigned char}')

Comment: What type is `from` ?

Comment: Looks like its uint8_t

Comment: std::string s = std::string("newData") + (char*)from + ";";

Comment: Is `from` something printable then?  Or is it a binary thing that represents an address?  If the former, then ok.  If the latter, this won't work reliably.  I'll need more details on what `from` is meant to represent (and why you are trying to add it to a string)

Comment: What I'm getting at, is do you need to convert `from` into a string first before adding it to your message?

Comment: I've updated my answer. `#include <sstream>` if needed to pick up the `ostringstream` class.

Comment: Looks like your solution worked. Although the Arduino freezes after some time. I've read that this can happen when using String class. Is there a way to bypass this? Maybe only use char if it is even possible?

Comment: The freeze has nothing to do with the std::string class.  Given your current experience in C++ is limited, you likely have other bugs not covered by the code you shared. Use a tool like Valgrind to find buffer overruns, memory leaks, and heap corruption issues that can cause the system or program to do weird things. I also fixed a typo in my code above.